# Vtune results are weird

Tags: c, intel, instructions, intel-vtune

I profiled two programs by using Intel Vtune one that is optimized and the other is not, and the results were a little weird, the Instructions Retired in both were about 7,400,000, and in the CPI the rate of the optimized program was higher than the un-optimized program! So, can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: How many samples have you collected? Make sure there are reasonable number of samples collected in both cases by running workload for at least a sec. Please post the code as well, if possible.